# Cannot convert the expression type of AnyObject? to type '$T3'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, ios8

i am trying to get an imageview by passing image in Swift. But i got an error.

```
func setImageViewForImage(image:UIImage) -> UIImageView?{
        var image_pmc:UIImage = image
        var imageView_pmc:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image_pmc)
        imageView_pmc.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2 - image_pmc.size.width/2, 10, image_pmc.size.width, image_pmc.size.height)
        return imageView_pmc
    }
```

function call:

`var imgView = setImageViewForImage(response)` //error

//response is UIImage

Comment: Ok. i got it. i have to cast response as image. 
 var imgView = self.setImageViewForImage(response! as UIImage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because your `response` variable is of `AnyObject?` type, which cannot be implicitly cast to `UIImage`, and however, being an optional, it must be unwrapped before passing to `setImageViewForImage` (which expects a non optional).

You should use optional binding combined with optional downcast as follows:

```
if let response = response as? UIImage {
    myClass.setImageViewForImage(response)
}
```

where `myClass` is an instance of the class containing the `setImageViewForImage` method - presumably an instance of (a subclass of) `UIView`.

Note that I am making the assumption that `response` actually contains an `UIImage` - its name makes me think it's something you receive from a REST API call or similar.

Note that avoiding the optional binding and using explicit cast:

```
myClass.setImageViewForImage(response as UIImage)
```

is not safe because if response is nil or it doesn't contain a `UIImage` instance, the app will most likely crash.